# Rider IDE - 'No projects to run' when trying to run/debug application

Tags: rider

When I try to run/debug my application with Rider 2020.1 I am unable to as there is no project selected in the run configurations. When I try to select a project it displays 'No projects to run'
[Rider run configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zXlW.png)

This has only started happening since I downloaded Rider 2020.1. I am still able ti run my projects with the same settings in Rider 2019.3.4

Has anyone had this before? Or any ideas on how to get my projects to run again?

Thanks.

Comment: Which type of project are you running? Did you try to create a new "configuration" which points to the project you would like to run? (Press SHIFT button 2 times and then type Edit Configurations...)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I'm trying to run a windows application. I have tried to Edit Configurations but I can't select a project to run. I can create a .Net executable that runs the .exe